# Determine sum of numpy array while excluding certain values

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, sum

I would like to determine the sum of a two dimensional `numpy` array. However, elements with a certain value I want to exclude from this summation. What is the most efficient way to do this?

For example, here I initialize a two dimensional `numpy` array of 1s and replace several of them by 2:

```
import numpy

data_set = numpy.ones((10, 10))

data_set[4][4] = 2
data_set[5][5] = 2
data_set[6][6] = 2
```

How can I sum over the elements in my two dimensional array while excluding all of the 2s? Note that with the 10 by 10 array the correct answer should be 97 as I replaced three elements with the value 2.

I know I can do this with nested for loops. For example:

```
elements = []
for idx_x in range(data_set.shape[0]):
  for idx_y in range(data_set.shape[1]):
    if data_set[idx_x][idx_y] != 2:
      elements.append(data_set[idx_x][idx_y])

data_set_sum = numpy.sum(elements)
```

However on my actual data (which is very large) this is too slow. What is the correct way of doing this?

Comment: Could you provide an example of input and expected output ? And what did you try so far ?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Use numpy's capability of [indexing with boolean arrays](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/user/basics.indexing.html). In the below example `data_set!=2` evaluates to a boolean array which is `True` whenever the element is not 2 (and has the correct shape). So `data_set[data_set!=2]` is a fast and convenient way to get an array which doesn't contain a certain value. Of course, the boolean expression can be more complex.

```
In [1]: import numpy as np
In [2]: data_set = np.ones((10, 10))
In [4]: data_set[4,4] = 2
In [5]: data_set[5,5] = 2
In [6]: data_set[6,6] = 2
In [7]: data_set[data_set != 2].sum()
Out[7]: 97.0
In [8]: data_set != 2
Out[8]: 
array([[ True,  True,  True,  True,  True,  True,  True,  True,  True,
         True],
       [ True,  True,  True,  True,  True,  True,  True,  True,  True,
         True],
       ...
       [ True,  True,  True,  True,  True,  True,  True,  True,  True,
         True]], dtype=bool)
```

Comment: @TheDude Edited the answer to fit your more specific question

Comment: Thank you Korem. I only made my edit since my question was found to be too broad. It is nice to match the answer to the question

Answer (score 5):

Without numpy, the solution is not much more complex:

```
x = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7]
sum(y for y in x if y != 7)
# 21
```

Works for a list of excluded values too:

```
# set is faster for resolving `in`
exl = set([1,2,3])
sum(y for y in x if y not in exl)
# 22
```

Answer (score 1):

Using `np.sum`s `where=` argument, we avoid the need for array copying which would otherwise be triggered from using advanced array indexing:

```
>>> import numpy as np
>>> data_set = np.ones((10,10))
>>> data_set[(4,5,6),(4,5,6)] = 2
>>> np.sum(data_set, where=data_set != 2)
97.0
>>> data_set.sum(where=data_set != 2)
97.0
```

https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.sum.html

> Advanced indexing always returns a copy of the data (contrast with basic slicing that returns a view).

https://numpy.org/doc/stable/user/basics.indexing.html#advanced-indexing

Answer (score 0):

How about this way that makes use of numpy's boolean capabilities.

We simply set all the values that meet the specification to zero before taking the sum, that way we don't change the shape of the array as we would if we were to filter them from the array.

The other benefit of this is that it means we can sum along axis after the filter is applied.

```
import numpy

data_set = numpy.ones((10, 10))

data_set[4][4] = 2
data_set[5][5] = 2
data_set[6][6] = 2

print "Sum", data_set.sum()

another_set = numpy.array(data_set) # Take a copy, we'll need that later

data_set[data_set == 2] = 0  # Set all the values that are 2 to zero
print "Filtered sum", data_set.sum()
print "Along axis", data_set.sum(0), data_set.sum(1)
```

Equally we could use any other boolean to set the data we wish to exclude from the sum.

```
another_set[(another_set > 1) & (another_set < 3)] = 0
print "Another filtered sum", another_set.sum()
```